# what up with my mongodb. mongod terminal command not running it shows this

Tags: linux, mongodb

IM new to mongodb . & i use linux mint as my machine and in that i tried to install mongodb in it. Now when i run mongod in linux terminal i get this lines.

```
    2020-04-05T14:08:30.899+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6844 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=meon1-Vostro-3558
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.5
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 2261279b51ea13df08ae708ff278f0679c59dc32
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 E  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp 684
2020-04-05T14:08:30.936+0530 F  -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

While `sudo systemctl` status mongodb show it`s running. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check your /tmp folder and see if file mongodb-27017.sock exists.

if yes then please remove it-

```
sudo rm -rf mongodb-27017.sock
```